# How to optimize wordpress and squid

Tags: wordpress, squid

Hi I'm using squid to speed up an installation of wordpress (running on lighty).

unfortuately it seeems that squid is getting too many MISSes.

I think this depends on the Vary: Cookie header that lighty sends with every request.

how can I remove that header?

Answer (score 0):

If there's any chance of different users getting a different page based on their cookie, you want the Vary: Cookie header in there even at the expense of lower hit rates. Otherwise user X may wind up getting user Y's cached page. Is this header being set on static content (i.e. images, .js, etc) as well as the page HTML?